# ggplot2: Thresholds for scale_alpha()

Tags: r, colors, ggplot2, alpha

Is it possible to specify thresholds for color-scales?

Look at this example:

```
xy <- expand.grid(x=1:20,y=1:20)
xyd <- data.frame(xy,z=runif(400),a=rowSums(xy)/40)
g <- ggplot(xyd, aes(x=x, y=y, fill=z, alpha=a)) + 
       geom_tile() + 
       scale_alpha(range=c(0,1), limits=c(0.5,1))
g
```

[image: Scale_alpha only applies to values within the given limits]

What I want is that Values of a below 0.5 get an alpha value of 0 so that the lower left half will be invisible. Obviously I could transform the original data but that would destroy the legend.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The threshold is working and the values outside that threshold are set to `NA`; the problem is that an `alpha` of `NA` is getting rendered as full opacity.  Setting the `na.value` on the scale to `0` gets the results you want.

```
ggplot(xyd, aes(x=x, y=y, fill=z, alpha=a)) + 
       geom_tile() + 
       scale_alpha(range=c(0,1), limits=c(0.5,1), na.value = 0)
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

None of my attempts to use the scales to control alpha were completely successful.  My best attempt was to use `ifelse` to control the value of a:

```
ggplot(xyd, aes(x=x, y=y, fill=z)) + 
  geom_tile(aes(alpha=ifelse(a<=0.5, 0, a))) +
  scale_alpha(range=c(0,1))
```

[image]

---

So, a different approach is required: remove the values that you don't want to plot from the data:

```
xyd <- with(xyd, xyd[a>0.5, ])

ggplot(xyd, aes(x=x, y=y, fill=z)) + 
  geom_tile(aes(alpha=a))
```

[image]

Comment: But look, the alpha values for the diagonal pixels are a lot less transparent then in my example.
What would work is: `ggplot(xyd, aes(x=x, y=y, fill=z)) + 
  geom_tile(aes(alpha=ifelse(a<=0.5, 0.5, a))) +
  scale_alpha(range=c(0,1), limits=c(0.5,1))`

But how do I then let the legend know, that there are also values below 0.5 ?